# IOS drag one view to another view ipad app

Tags: ios, ipad, drag-and-drop

i have create a new ipad application like this image
left side view have a one tableView and right side in second viewController so client need when user drag a row table view to secondView Controller then make a new view in second view 
so if is any hope any link to drag and drop ipad applecation please share with me , and one more is like two Section ipad application and left side have tabbar please share with me [image]

Comment: This is best for your requirement - https://github.com/Oblong/OBDragDrop

Comment: some more example link you have like tableview to collectionview its easy for me , in this example scroller view using so its deficult to manage right side view

Comment: I have used the same for `UITableView` and `UIScrollView`. You can do it with `UICollectionView` too. How ever follow this link and take look on different examples - https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=drag

Comment: @Kampai sir, please one more help me , i don't understand In right side scrollerview how to set new view size , Please help me , would u please give me your demo u have create uitableview and ScrollerView please send me demo code on my mail ,nishant.incarnate@gmail.com please help me sir

Comment: Ok. I'll provide you demo.